# Consistency level LOCAL_ONE is not supported for this operation. Supported consistency levels are: LOCAL_QUORUM

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

I am working with AWS keyspaces and trying to insert data from C# but getting this error."Consistency level LOCAL_ONE is not supported for this operation. Supported consistency levels are: LOCAL_QUORUM". can anyone please help out here.

**AWS keyspace**

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS "DevOps"
   WITH REPLICATION={'class': 'SingleRegionStrategy'} ;
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "DevOps"."projectdetails" (
"id" UUID PRIMARY KEY,
"name" text,
"lastupdatedtime" timestamp,
"baname" text,
"customerid" UUID)
```

**C# code**

```
 public async Task AddRecord(List<projectdetails> projectDetails)
        {

            try
            {
                if (projectDetails.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in projectDetails)
                    {
                        projectdetails projectData = new projectdetails();
                        projectData.id = item.id;
                        projectData.name = item.name;
                        projectData.baname = "Vishal";
                        projectData.lastupdatedtime = item.lastupdatedtime;
                        projectData.customerid = 1;
                        await mapper.InsertAsync<projectdetails>(projectData);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) 
            { 

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error clearly says that you need to use correct consistency level `LOCAL_QUORUM` instead of the `LOCAL_ONE` that is used by default.  [AWS documentation says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/consistency.html) that for write operations, it's only the consistency level supported.  You can set consistency level by using [the version of `InsertAsync`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.6/html/M_Cassandra_Mapping_ICqlWriteAsyncClient_InsertAsync__1.htm) that accepts the [CqlQueryOptions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.6/html/T_Cassandra_Mapping_CqlQueryOptions.htm), like this (maybe create instance of the query options only once, during initialization of the application):

```
mapper.InsertAsync<projectdetails>(projectData, 
  new CqlQueryOptions().SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LocalQuorum))
```

Comment: I am amazed at how many nuances there are to using AWS Managed Cassandra.  In fact, they should just call it "AWS Nuanced Cassandra."  LOL

Comment: frankly speaking, DataStax Astra also has such requirement - you can't use LOCAL_ONE for writing... But if I remember correctly, driver should automatically adjust it when detecting that it's using secure bundle