# Provided value LOCAL_ONE is not allowed for Write Consistency Level

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

I'm trying to connect my java spring boot application to cassandra astra db with the cql proxy running with docker-compose.
I got this error :

> `com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Provided value LOCAL_ONE is not allowed for Write Consistency Level (disallowed values are: [ANY, ONE, LOCAL_ONE])`

How to resolve this error please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consistency level LOCAL\_ONE is not supported for this operation. Supported consistency levels are: LOCAL\_QUORUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62266181/consistency-level-local-one-is-not-supported-for-this-operation-supported-consi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Astra DB Guardrails](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/plan/planning.html#_cassandra_query_language_cql) the supported consistency levels are:

> Supported consistency levels: Reads: Any supported consistency level
> is permitted.
> Single-region writes: LOCAL_QUORUM and LOCAL_SERIAL
>
> Multi-region writes: EACH_QUORUM and SERIAL

You need to use local_quorum for the writes as a minimum, one / local_one is not supported.

Comment: Can I define the consistency level on my docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: No, Astra DB has specific guardrails - even for a locally deployed Cassandra / DSE cluster, the consistency level is a facet of the application configuration / choices, and not the cluster choice.

Comment: I set the value to local_quorum, I can insert just two entries but when I try to isert the third entry, I get this error: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S

Comment: @alia - please create another question with the details, stack trace, code sample etc.